# Count all the ascending array of integer array

Tags: php, arrays, int

I have a problem: "Count all the ascending array of integer array".

**My code:**

```
<?php
$arrInt = array(1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 1, 2);

function numArrChildAscending($index, $indexcount, $array = array()){
    $numcount = 0;

    if ($index >= count($array) || $index < 1 || $index + $indexcount >= count($array)){
        return $numcount;
    }

    $flag = true;

    for ($i = $index; $i <= ($index + $indexcount - 1); $i++){
        if ($array[$i] <= $array[$i - 1]){
            $flag = false;
            break;
        }
    }

    if ($flag == true){
        $numcount++;
    }

    //echo 'count 1 :' . $numcount . '<br />';

    for ($i = $index + 1; $i < count($array); $i++){
        $numcount = $numcount + numArrChildAscending($i, $indexcount, $array);
    }

    //echo 'count 2 :' . $numcount . '<br />';

    for ($i = $indexcount; $i < count($array); $i++) { 
        $numcount = $numcount + numArrChildAscending($index, $i, $array);
    }

    //echo 'count 3 :' . $numcount . '<br />';


    return $numcount;
}

echo numArrChildAscending(1, 2, $arrInt);
```

**This is the result:**

```
Fatal error: Maximum function nesting level of '256' reached, aborting!
in D:\VertrigoServ\www\learningphp.vn\index.php on line 7
```

Answer (score 0):

Put this line in your php file.

```
ini_set('xdebug.max_nesting_level', $limit)
```

Get sure you've got xdebug installed

Comment: i set `ini_set('xdebug.max_nesting_level', 2000);` and `ERR_CONNECTION_RESET`

Answer (score -1):

Edit your `php.ini` file : search for `xdebug.max_nesting_level` in the `XDebug section`. Increase the value.

Comment: I dont find in php.ini file

Comment: I downloaded it and, where I move it?